# WordPress ajax call is being called recursively

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using this function to run an ajax code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', array(&$this,'ChatAjax'));
```

This code should be called each 30 sec, I am using this code

```
function CheckRequests(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
    url : Chat.ajaxurl,
    type:'POST',
    data: 'action=my_action',
    success: function(data){jQuery('#LiveChat').html(data);}  
    });
    window.setInterval(function(){CheckRequests()}, 30000);
}
```

It works more than fine except, the function is not called every 30 sec. The code is called each second, again and again, so the whole web site was suspended by my hosting provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the code for setting up the callback is inside the function scope, and this is causing recursive call.

```
function CheckRequests(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url : Chat.ajaxurl,
        type:'POST',
        data: 'action=my_action',
        success: function(data){jQuery('#LiveChat').html(data);}  
    });
}//close the bracket here
//call should be outside the function scope 
window.setInterval(CheckRequests, 30000);
```

Comment: Deni you just save my day :D Thanks a lot The solution was in front of me all the time :D